# Designing 12v DC UPS

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, ups

My requirements are:
I need a UPS system which supplies power to a 9 volt modem. UPS should Charge 12v battery (SLA , charging curent 800ma), and it should have overcharge/discharge protection system [optional: it should show the battery capacity with four leds(25% interval)]. I want to achieve this without using ADC.
I can make 230V AC to 12v DC converter with step down transformer. Switching from mains to battery can also be achieved with two diodes. But i want to make overcharge/discharge with led indicator which i cant figure out without ADC. Is there any way to achieve this without microcontroller and ADC. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I am thinking about something like this. I have designed this circuit on my own. But i have no idea how to link these two switches to charge level indicator.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of D1 and D2? D1 is useless, and D2 will prevent the battery from being charged at all.

Comment: This picture is just a reference to switching. This circuit does not explain charging mechanism. Thank you.

Comment: So what is your question then? The simplest way to have a LED charge indicator is to [buy one](https://www.google.de/shopping/product/9806264896801582518?sclient=psy-ab&biw=1024&bih=480&q=12v%20battery%20charge%20indicator&oq=12v%20battery%20charge%20indicator&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.95277229,d.bGQ&tch=1&ech=1&psi=_3Z4VbusI6WCzAPtrIHwDA.1433958145230.5&prds=paur:ClkAsKraX4fDr0Ha5JF4meOetgPFUk-slQrk_gX2-0SgDh3qCm_zPVhJg6v-9Et6ml23hTy7xHvtjKGf0qmzfb2ydoFMywXV_R6mVkfKAQHSI8-Dr21FFOPihRIZAFPVH73zLPbIvpoY_Tag6QB6EIi9fY-m3A,hsec:specs), the same is true for the charging circuit and DC/DC converter

Comment: If you are just trying to solve a practical problem, I suggest that you should just buy a commercial battery charger and connect it to your battery. Then run a DC-DC converter from the battery to supply 9V to your modem. The DC-DC converter should be rated to work from 16v down to around 11V. You can buy or design your own DC-DC. Instead of LED's to indicate battery level, just connect a low-cost panel meter to monitor battery voltage.

Comment: Yes this is a practical problem. But i want to design it myself.

Comment: You should be able to indicate the charge level using a voltage divider ladder.

Comment: You already have this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about trying to use one switch to change from (Charge battery, power device from AC) to (power device from battery,) then what you need is a single pole double throw (SPDT) switch.

It looks like this electrically:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNXMvt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>